# Authentication in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication

I begin with ASP.NET and I have a problem with authentication.

This is the code:

web.config

```xml
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/users/login" timeout="3000"  />
  </authentication>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
</system.web>
```

login

```cs
public ActionResult login()
{
    if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
    {
        if (Request.Form["email"] == null || Request.Form["password"] == null)
            ViewData["error"] = "form_error";
        else
        {
            User user = this.dal.authUser(
            Request.Form["email"],
            Request.Form["password"]);
            if (user == null)
                ViewData["error"] = "auth_error";
            else
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.id.ToString(), false);
                return Redirect("/profiles/" + user.id);
            }
        }
    }
    return (View());
}
```

profile controller

```cs
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult get(int id)
{
    ViewData["auth"] = false;
    if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        ViewData["auth"] = true;
    Response.Write(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
    Profile profile = this.dal.getProfile(id);
    if (profile == null)
        return View("~/Views/error404.cshtml");
    ViewData["profile"] = profile;
    return View();
}
```

and View for get a profile

```
@using Plume.Areas.Users.Models;

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Layout/layout.cshtml";
    Variables.pageTitle = "Profil";
    Profile profile = (Profile)ViewData["profile"];
    bool auth = (bool)ViewData["auth"];
}

@{ 
    if (auth)
    {
        <h1>Auth</h1>
    }
}

<p>
    ceci est le profil de : 
    @profile.username
    <br />
    dont l'email est :
    @profile.user.email
</p>
```

So, when I log, a cookie called `.ASPXAUTH` is returned, but in the view for a profile, the `h1` isn't displayed.

What is not correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using formsauthentication for login and use HttpContext.Current.User.Identity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32564984/using-formsauthentication-for-login-and-use-httpcontext-current-user-identity)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [User.Identity.IsAuthenticated returns false after setting cookie and validating](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14508495/11683)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove or comment below line in `Web.Config` file.

**Web.Config :**

```
 <modules>
  <!--<remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />-->
</modules>
```